# I don't know how to solve equations used in the golden ratio

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Today i was reading something from golden ratio and i don't understand how some equations where solved for example:

Im told that $\phi_{n+1}=B_{n+1} + \frac {A_n}{B_n}$. What I don't understand is that then it says that:

$$ B_{n+1} = B_n+A_n \quad \mbox{and that} \quad A_{n+1} = B_n$$

How is that solved?

Hope you can understand.

Comment: I've placed your question into Mathjax form. Please post in this manner in the future.

Comment: Is this an article that be accessed online? I can easily explain what the recurrence means, but without context it is difficult to know where they are going with it.

Comment: Hi, what is Mathjax, actually im new using this kind of websiteand im just a person who likes to read topics about math so Im dont know to much.

Comment: http://nrich.maths.org/2737

Comment: This is the place where i was reading the article, actually i want to know how the two equations for the An+1 and Bn+1 where get

Comment: @kprincipe, If $$X_n=\frac{b_n}{a_n},X_{n+1}=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article in question is missing some details. Particularly, if you are to diagonalize the matrix that is generated from that recurrence, you can raise it to an nth power and obtain a formula that relates fibonacci like sequences.

However, to see this in detail, it is best to look at what happens to $\phi$ as you generate the repeated fraction.

We can start with $1$ then repeatedly apply $\phi_n = 1 + \frac{1}{\phi_{n-1}}$ and we get $ \frac{1}{1}, \frac{2}{1}, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{3}, \frac{8}{5}, \cdots  $. Now what do you notice about the numerator and denominator?

They are fibonacci like sequences. Each number is the sum of the two previous numbers. In other words, $\phi_n = \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} $. This would have been a good observation by the author, but alas, he had other goals.

However. In building the sequence, we can still represent the numerator and denominator in a different way.

Notice the numerator is always the previous numerator plus the previous denominator, or else $ b_{n+1} = \frac{b_n}{a_n} $.

Do you think you can figure out $a_n$?

Ahh, screw it. I started writing this, so I might as well finish it.

Notice first,

$$ \begin{bmatrix} F_{n+1} \\ F_{n} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} b_{n+1} \\ a_{n+1} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} b_n \\ a_n \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix} b_1 \\ a_1 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Lets calculate the eigenvalues of

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}. $$

We have the determinant of

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1-\lambda & 1 \\1 & -\lambda\end{bmatrix}, $$

which is $ (\lambda - 1)\lambda - 1 = \lambda^2 - \lambda - 1 $ which has the two solutions $\phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\beta = \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} $. You can see where this is going. If we solve the eigenvectors and diagonalize the matrix and raise it to the power n, we have

$$ \frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{bmatrix} \beta & \phi \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \beta & 0 \\0 & \phi \end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -\phi \\-1 & \beta \end{bmatrix} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{bmatrix} \beta^{n+1} - \phi^{n+1} & \beta\phi^{n+1} - \phi\beta^{n+1}  \\\beta^{n} - \phi^{n} & \beta\phi^{n} - \phi\beta^{n} \end{bmatrix}. $$

This of course is a lot more interesting if you make the connection with fibonacci, because it results in $F_n = \frac{\phi^n - \beta^n}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: yeah, i see it will be bn.I mean an+1 will be bn

Comment: One last question, when the author states both equations for an+1 and bn+1, my doubt was how it was solved with algebra, I tried clear bn+1 to see if I was able to get that bn+1 was equal to an+bn but dont know how the author got it with algebra

Comment: Notice $$ \phi_n = \frac{b_n}{a_n} = \frac{a_{n-1} + b_{n-1}}{a_n} = \frac{a_{n-1} + b_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}} = 1 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}} = 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{b_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}}} = 1 + \frac{1}{\phi_{n-1}} $$ which is how it is defined.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I was a little lost with the part of eigenvectors and searched and saw that it was linear algebra and I have never seen that so I will go to khanacademy and try to understad better about linear algebra but you helped me understand some of the logic pretty well. Thanks for the help and taking your time to help me

Comment: @kprincipe Not a problem! It's awesome seeing someone actively developing their learning. Maybe this can be something you can look back at once you've covered a reasonable amount of linear algebra. Also, note that it's usually good practise to choose a best answer when your problem is resolved here!

Comment: im trying to vote for you answer but the systems says I dont have enough reputation and don't allows me to do it.im so sorry if im being dumb this is my first time using this page

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers :)